# Add views vertically in LinearLayout

Tags: android, view, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to add `views` vertically in `LinearLayout` like the pic below :

[image]

the code below gives me something like this :

[image]

```
 private void configure(View view) {
        LinearLayout palletContainer = view.findViewById(R.id.palette_container);
        fillPalletColors(mPalette, palletContainer);
    }
private void fillPalletColors(List<Integer> colors, LinearLayout paletteContainer) {
        if (getActivity() != null && isAdded()) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
                for (int color : colors) {
                    View palletColor = inflater.inflate(R.layout.suggested_color_item_center, paletteContainer, false);
                    palletColor.setBackgroundColor(color);
                    paletteContainer.addView(palletColor);
                }
            }
    }
```

**XML** :

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical">

     <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/palette_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" />
  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What do you pass in for `paletteContainer` to this function?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice thank you for your comment, `LinearLayout palletContainer = view.findViewById(R.id.palette_container);
        fillPalletColors(mPalette, palletContainer);` ,I've updated the question

Comment: Try setting orientation programmatically `palletContainer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);`